# Работа с файлами Python. Дозапись

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
    x = input()
a = list(x.split()) 
b = 0
maxC, minC = 0, 99999999999999
with open("nums.txt", "a+") as f:
    for nums in a:
        f.write(nums + '\n')
print('Ваши числа успешно записаны в файл.')
f.close()
with open("nums.txt", 'r') as f:
    print('Открываю ваш файл...')
    for line in f:
        print(line, end="" )
        c = line
        c = float(c)
        if c > maxC:
            maxC = c
        elif c < minC:
            minC = c
        b += c
f.close()
with open("nums.txt", 'a+') as f:
    f.write(str(b) + '\n')
    f.write(str(maxC) + '\n')
    f.write(str(minC) + '\n')
f.close()
```

Этa программа записывает цифры в файл, потом считает их сумму, максимум и минимум и записывает в конец файла
Как сделать, чтобы после второго запуска программы, цифры которые я введу дозаписались к прошлым и программа опять посчитала максимум, минимум и сумму и дозаписала их в конец файла?
У меня при втором запуске остаются максимум, минимум и сумма и после них еще дозаписываются новые цифры.
На выходе после двух запусков: Жирным выделено лишнее
123
43
354
329
327
**1176.0
354.0
43.0**
123
437
934
12
4255.0
1176.0
12.0

Comment: При запуске: если файл есть считать его, убрать из него последнюю строку с максимумом и минимумом, добавить новые значения, записать все значения в файл, посчитать максимум и минимум и их следом записать

Comment: как убрать строки из файла?

Comment: Если памяти хватает, то считать весь файл в список, убрать из списка ненужные строки, открыть файл на запись (`mode='w'`), записать строки